# The relationship between the standing wave energy and its harmonic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

My question is this: suppose we create two different standing waves in a string . So, is the energy of the standing wave dependent on the frequency of the wave ?(assume that the amplitude is unchanged)

My guess is this: the energy of the standing wave is equal to the sum of the energy of the individual waves. Since the energy of individual waves remain the same( as the amplitude is constant) , the energy of the standing wave remains constant too. Am I right?

Comment: If by "amplitude" you mean the displacement of the string from the rest position, then in higher frequency modes the string must move faster to cover the same distance in a cycle.

Comment: What do you mean by "remains constant"? Between what and what?